# IPackageStatsObserver cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android

I am trying to calculate the total cache used by all the apps in the android device. I found this code but have only this error `IPackageStatsObserver cannot be resolved to a type`. How to get rid of this error. However I tried Ctrl+Shift+O but nothing imported !

```
public long totalCacheSize()
{
     totalSize=0;

        PackageManager packageManager = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();


         /* List<PackageInfo> packs = packageManager
          .getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);*/
         // PackageManager.GET_META_DATA

        List<PackageInfo> packs = packageManager
                .getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

        for (int i = 0; i < packs.size(); i++) {

            PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);

            Method getPackageSizeInfo;
            try {
                getPackageSizeInfo = packageManager.getClass().getMethod(
                        "getPackageSizeInfo", String.class,
                        IPackageStatsObserver.class); //error here

                getPackageSizeInfo.invoke(packageManager, p.packageName,
                        new IPackageStatsObserver.Stub() { //error here

                            public void onGetStatsCompleted(
                                    PackageStats pStats, boolean succeeded)
                                    throws RemoteException {

                                totalSize = totalSize + pStats.cacheSize;
                                Log.d("size", totalSize+"");
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "size"+totalSize, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }

                );
            } catch (Exception e) {
                try {
                    getPackageSizeInfo = packageManager.getClass().getMethod(
                            "getPackageSizeInfo", String.class,
                            IPackageStatsObserver.class); //error here

                    getPackageSizeInfo.invoke(packageManager, p.packageName,
                            new IPackageStatsObserver.Stub() { // error here

                                public void onGetStatsCompleted(
                                        PackageStats pStats, boolean succeeded)
                                        throws RemoteException {

                                    totalSize = totalSize + pStats.cacheSize;
                                    Log.d("size", totalSize+"");
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "size"+totalSize, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }

                    );
                } catch (Exception ee) {
                    Log.d("eeeeeeeeeee", "error");
                    ee.printStackTrace();
                } 
            } 

        }
        Log.d("return size", totalSize+"");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "return size"+totalSize, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return totalSize;
}
```

Can anyone have better solution for this or know how to get rid of this. Please let me know. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

The class `IPackageStatsObserver` is not available in the Android SDK and therefore cannot be revolved at compile time. The fix is to look for it at compile time by changing your code to:

```
getPackageSizeInfo = packageManager.getClass()
    .getMethod("getPackageSizeInfo",
        String.class, Class.forName("android.content.pm.IPackageStatsObserver");
```

Comment: 2 out of 4 errors gone , but I still have error in this line `new IPackageStatsObserver.Stub() `

Comment: Easy, load the `Stub` class using `Class.forName()`, find the default constructor and invoke it to get a new instance of a `Stub`.

Comment: Sorry, I dint get you. Please explain more, I am still facing this issue

Comment: Please tell me the code to load the Stub class using Class.forName(), & then finding the default constructor and invoke it to get a new instance of a Stub?

Answer (score 0):

**Import the relevant AIDLs** (`PackageStats` and `IPackageStatsObserver`) into our project and have ADT generate stubs. With the stubs generated, we can simply use reflection to call the hidden `getPackageSize` method and `retrieve the PackageStats` instance in the stub's onGetStatsCompleted callback method:

and for detail [Read this article](http://www-jo.se/f.pfleger/android-package-size)

**IPackageStatsObserver.aidl**

```
/*
**
** Copyright 2007, The Android Open Source Project
**
** Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
** you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
** You may obtain a copy of the License at
**
**     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
**
** Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
** distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
** WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
** See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
** limitations under the License.
*/
package android.content.pm;
import android.content.pm.PackageStats;
/**
 * API for package data change related callbacks from the Package Manager.
 * Some usage scenarios include deletion of cache directory, generate
 * statistics related to code, data, cache usage(TODO)
 * {@hide}
 */
oneway interface IPackageStatsObserver {

    void onGetStatsCompleted(in PackageStats pStats, boolean succeeded);
}
```

**PackageStats.aidl**

```
/* //device/java/android/android/view/WindowManager.aidl
**
** Copyright 2007, The Android Open Source Project
**
** Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); 
** you may not use this file except in compliance with the License. 
** You may obtain a copy of the License at 
**
**     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 
**
** Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software 
** distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, 
** WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. 
** See the License for the specific language governing permissions and 
** limitations under the License.
*/
package android.content.pm;
parcelable PackageStats;
```

**Edit**

create **package name**  `android.content.pm` and add `IPackageStatsObserver.aidl` and `PackageStats.aidl`  files to it.

Comment: I dont know How will my error mentioned in question be gone, pls tell that